# Take and put input value from A to B input

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem:** User entered input value while the page is loading and JS is not executed. `.blur` function is unable to take input and paste it into other input value. So the purpose of this code is useless until page is fully loaded and JS is executed.

**Idea:** Binding the submit button to `.blur` function so when user click on submit the `.blur` function can recheck the input value and paste into the other input.

*Disabling the submit button until page is completed loaded and JS is executed to remove the `disabled` label from the input submit.*

I can't make it to work with click function + .blur function to work together.

```
    var input = jQuery("#takehere");
    var copycat = jQuery("#drophere");

    jQuery(input).on("blur", function() {
    copycat.val(jQuery(this).val());
    jQuery("#send").removeAttr('disabled');

    });
```

```
<input type="text" id="takehere" />
<input type="text" id="drophere" />
<input type="submit" id="send" disabled />
```

Comment: `click function` - what click function?

Comment: @JaromandaX `.click(function()`

Comment: Why not just enable the submit as the last line of the JS, so you know that the blur listener has been added? Although really I would be worried about a) why is your script taking so long to load and b) what happens if JS is turned off in the browser

Comment: it's not in the code you posted?